# VSP1812: This report contains no process information

Tags: visual-studio-2012, profiler

I ran Visual Studio 2012 performance profiler tools via command line and ran into the below issue and spent hours to figure out the issue.

VSP1812: This report contains no process information.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to the fact that one of dll and pdb were not of the same version.